# How to use Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I cut off the colors after the comma and leave only the model names?

source table: cars

| id | auto |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lada Vesta, grey |
| 2 | BMW F80, red |
| 3 | Hyundai Elantra, red |
| ... | ... |

```
CREATE TABLE cars(
    id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    auto nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO cars values(1,'Lada Vesta, grey');
INSERT INTO cars values(2,'BMW F80, red');
INSERT INTO cars values(3,'Hyundai Elantra');
```

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING(auto, CHARINDEX(' ', auto) +1, LEN(auto)) AS model
FROM cars
```

It turns out like this:

| id | model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Vesta, grey |
| 2 | F80, red |
| 3 | Elantra, red |
| ... | ... |

And it should be

| id | model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Vesta |
| 2 | F80 |
| 3 | Elantra |
| ... | ... |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: What would happen if you have an "Alfa Romeo Tonale, Blue"? You have no *good* delimiter for the manufacturer and model. Fix the data at the source and have *3* columns to start with.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 basically, `SUBSTRING(<whole string>. startPos, subLength)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
DECLARE @cars TABLE(id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, auto nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO @cars values(1,'Lada Vesta, grey'), (2,'BMW F80, red'), (3,'Hyundai Elantra');

SELECT *, SUBSTRING(auto, 0, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',auto) > 1 THEN CHARINDEX(',',auto) ELSE LEN(auto)+1 END)
  FROM @cars
```

| id | auto | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lada Vesta, grey | Lada Vesta |
| 2 | BMW F80, red | BMW F80 |
| 3 | Hyundai Elantra | Hyundai Elantra |

Here we're using `SUBSTRING` with `CHARINDEX` on the **auto** column. The `CHARINDEX` is within a `CASE` expression because your string may not contain a comma. If the `CHARINDEX` of ',' is greater than one we use it's value, if it's not then we use the length of the string plus one.

EDIT: Op requested to be able to parse a string like:
`MAKE MODEL, COLOUR`

```
DECLARE @cars TABLE(id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, auto nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO @cars values(1,'Lada Vesta, grey'), (2,'BMW F80, red'), (3,'Hyundai Elantra');

SELECT id, auto, 
SUBSTRING(auto, 0, CHARINDEX(' ',auto)) AS Make,
SUBSTRING(auto, CHARINDEX(' ',auto)+1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',auto) > 1 THEN CHARINDEX(',',auto)-(CHARINDEX(' ',auto))-1 ELSE LEN(auto)+1 END) AS Model,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',auto) > 1 THEN SUBSTRING(auto, CHARINDEX(',', auto)+2, LEN(auto)) END AS Colour
  FROM @cars;
```

| id | auto | Make | Model | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lada Vesta, grey | Lada | Vesta | grey |
| 2 | BMW F80, red | BMW | F80 | red |
| 3 | Hyundai Elantra | Hyundai | Elantra |  |

This is not fundamentally different, it's still using the same techniques and functions, but it is using some additional logic to figure out start and ending positions for each of the three values.

Comment: How to make it so that there is no Lada Vesta, it’s acceptable, but only Vesta?

Comment: You'd need to correct the entry for that, probably.
You could use a `REPLACE` - `RELACE(auto','Lada ','')` if you really had to, I guess.

Comment: Unless your example data is incorrect, and the strings should be: `Lada` `Vesta` `F80` `BMW` etc?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't fully disclose the essence of the question. In the topic, I added the final table, which should be. That is, 'Lada' is like a brand, and I need exactly the model, i.e. Vesta

Comment: Is your data always `<make> <model>, <color>` ?

Comment: Yes that's right. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using case and position:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE 
        WHEN POSITION(',' IN auto) > 0 
        THEN SUBSTRING(auto FROM POSITION(',' IN auto) + 1)
        ELSE auto 
    END AS model
FROM cars;
```

Comment: FYI `POSITION` is not a T-SQL function. I believe that would be MySQL and [maybe?] Postgres.

Comment: How to make it so that there is no Lada Vesta, it’s acceptable, but only Vesta?

Comment: To be fair, the OP tagged it as SQL / SQL-Server, which is a little ambiguous. PostGres and MySQL are SQL Servers, but they are not SQL-Server. OP could have added clarify by using the T-SQL tag.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**